# RecyclerView (horizontal) nested in BottomSheet preventing vertical scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androiddesignsupport, bottom-sheet

I have a `RecyclerView` using a `LinearLayoutManager` with `HORIZONTAL` orientation, nested inside a `FrameLayout` using the `BottomSheet` `Behavior`.

When attempting to drag vertically across the `RecyclerView`, the `BottomSheet` doesn't respond to the drag event. Presumably this is because vertical scrolling is disabled for a `LayoutManager` with horizontal orientation.

I've tried overriding `LinearLayoutManager.canScrollVertically()` and returning true. This *sort of* works.. If you drag vertically in a very careful manner, the `BottomSheet` will respond. As soon as any horizontal movement is involved however, the `BottomSheet` stops responding to vertical drag events.

I'm not sure if overriding `canScrollVertically()` is the right approach here - it certainly doesn't feel right from a UX point of view.

I've also noticed that if I use a `ViewPager` rather than a `RecyclerView` with a horizontally oriented `LayoutManager`, the `BottomSheet` responds to vertical swipe events as desired.

Is there some other method of `LayoutManager`, `RecyclerView`, `BottomSheet Behavior`, or something else altogether that can help propagate the vertical scroll events on to the `BottomSheet Behavior`?

There's an example of the problem here:

https://github.com/timusus/bottomsheet-test
(Problem can be reproduced with commit #f59a7031)

Just expand the first bottom sheet.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Where does the problem lies? In `FrameLayout`. `BottomSheet` works perfectly when put inside `CoordinatorLayout`. Then `BottomSheet` can pass it's scrolling state through `CoordinatorLayout` to other views put as direct children of `CoordinatorLayout`.

Why `RecyclerView` was not able to pass scroll state to `BottomSheet`? It is not a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`. But there exists a way to pass them: `RecyclerView` must be in put in view that implements [`NestedScrollingParent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingParent.html) and [`NestedScrollingChild`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html). The answer to that is: [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

So your `fragment_sheetX.xml` layouts should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Notice also `android:fillViewport="true"` as otherwise, your `RecyclerView` will not take whole height.

However it still will not work. Why? `RecyclerView` must be told to pass vertical scrolling to parent. How? The answer is `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`, but that is better described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533810/6507689).

Btw: `MultiSheetView` is a great feature and a very interesting approach to mobile UX design.

Comment: I suspected the`FrameLayout` preventing scroll events from propagating to the `CoordinatorLayout`. I think I got close to this solution at some point, but had trouble with the viewport problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: if the hierarchy is: NestedScrollView -> ConstraintLayout -> RecylerView, the RecyclerView scrolling doesn´t behave correctly...I can scroll down but not up. When trying to scroll up, the Bottomsheet (in this case NestedScrollView) collapses...any Idea?

Comment: This method causes the `RecyclerView` to have height equivalent to `wrap_content`, which is _terrible_ for performance as it causes `ViewHolder`s for all children to be inflated individually without reuse

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer solved my problem.

Comment: This will not recycle view inside recycle view..

Comment: @skm, have you found an answer, how to make RecylerView scrollable both ways in BottomSheet? I have the same problem in my project

Answer (score 0):

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Setting this in recyclerview solved the problem