# Android RecyclerView inside BottomSheetBehavior layout

Tags: android

The problem is that scroll is taken by `BottomSheetBehavior` and I cannot scroll vertically my items in `RecyclerView`. I'd like to scroll items from `RecyclerView` firstly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="view.activity.MyActivity">


    <!--my activity views-->

    <include layout="@layout/custom_bottom_sheet_view" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and code for `custom_bottom_sheet_view` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_searches"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp">

        <!--view peek-->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44747530/7917629

Comment: Keep an eye on your LayoutManager, it must support scrollbars. Linear one works out of the box.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
mRecycler.setOnTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Disallow NestedScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Allow NestedScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }

                // Handle RecyclerView touch events.
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

where `mRecycler` is your `RecylerView`

Comment: Thanks, tested with ListView

Answer (score 5):

You must add this code at layout of recyclerView:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

and this:

```
yourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

If you used recyclerview inside coordinatorLayout, check this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and in code use this:

```
yourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

If you want use recyclerView inside BottomSheetDialogFragment check this code:

Here is dialog layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

and your bottomSheetDialogFragment class is like this:

```
public class CustomDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private YourAdapter adapter;

    public CustomDialog() {
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void setupDialog(@NotNull final Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.your_dialog_layout, null);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, contentView);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);

        ((View) contentView.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
        Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(getDialog()).getWindow())
                .getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.SheetDialog);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        dialog.setOnShowListener(dialog1 -> {
            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog1;

            FrameLayout bottomSheet = d.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
        });

        // Do something with your dialog like setContentView() or whatever
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        initRV();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void initRV() {
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        adapter = new CarTypeRVAdapter(new CarCallBack(), new CarVHFactory());
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(50);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: recyclerview with height=wrap_content is a very bad idea... it will not recycle any views anymore

Comment: The question was about `BottomSheetBehavior` while this answer is about `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. Hence - "not an answer".

Answer (score 0):

If you use horizontal recyclerview under vertical recyclerview you should to set nestedScrollingEnabled="false" for horizontal recyclerview.